# maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test failed Error occurred in starting fork

Tags: java, maven, testing, cmd, maven-surefire-plugin

Trying to run the following maven command:

```
mvn test -X
```

Result:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-
plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) on project unit4-api-message-hub: Error 
occurred in starting fork, check output in log -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) on project unit4-api-message-hub: Error occurred in starting fork, check output in log
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:213)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:154)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:146)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:309)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:194)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:107)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:993)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:345)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:191)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Error occurred in starting fork, check output in log
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.SurefirePlugin.assertNoException(SurefirePlugin.java:159)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.SurefirePlugin.handleSummary(SurefirePlugin.java:148)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAfterPreconditionsChecked(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:650)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:586)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
        ... 20 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooterForkException: Error occurred in starting fork, check output in log
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:284)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeProvider(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:740)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAllProviders(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:682)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAfterPreconditionsChecked(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:648)
        ... 23 more
[ERROR]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

When i change the pom.xml to explicitly use **maven-surefire-plugin:2.20.1** it gives kind of error as with **maven-surefire-
    plugin:2.12.4**. 
What makes it even more strange is that I use the same installation set as my colleague and his works out of the box. Same OS (Windows 10) , same JAVA and Maven version same Git Repo. We already tried delete .m2 repo to relieve the system of cache.

I have a feeling that there is something wrong with CMD like *like the problem is with cmd /C exit /B 0* 
When trying to run a part of the command in windows CMD i get the following result:  *The system cannot find the path specified.*

```
C:\dev\workspace\MessageHub.JavaSdk\lucas-api-hub>C:\myPath\Java\jdk1.8.0_152\jre\bin\java -jar C:\dev\workspace\MessageHub.JavaSdk\lucas-api-hub\target\surefire\surefirebooter4393690082191226141.jar C:\dev\workspace\MessageHub.JavaSdk\lucas-api-hub\target\surefire\surefire2387848635455087535tmp C:\dev\workspace\MessageHub.JavaSdk\lucas-api-hub\target\surefire\surefire_08471100731569808288tmp
I,1,java.runtime.name,Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment
I,1,sun.boot.library.path,C:\\myPath\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_152\\jre\\bin
I,1,java.vm.version,25.152-b16
I,1,user.country.format,NL
I,1,java.vm.vendor,Oracle Corporation
I,1,java.vendor.url,http:\/\/java.oracle.com\/
I,1,path.separator,;
I,1,java.vm.name,Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
I,1,file.encoding.pkg,sun.io
I,1,user.script,
I,1,user.country,US
I,1,sun.java.launcher,SUN_STANDARD
I,1,sun.os.patch.level,
I,1,java.vm.specification.name,Java Virtual Machine Specification
I,1,user.dir,C:\\dev\\workspace\\MessageHub.JavaSdk\\lucas-api-hub
I,1,java.runtime.version,1.8.0_152-b16
I,1,java.awt.graphicsenv,sun.awt.Win32GraphicsEnvironment
I,1,basedir,C:\\dev\\workspace\\MessageHub.JavaSdk\\lucas-api-hub
I,1,java.endorsed.dirs,C:\\myPath\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_152\\jre\\lib\\endorsed
I,1,os.arch,amd64
I,1,surefire.real.class.path,C:\\dev\\workspace\\MessageHub.JavaSdk\\lucas-api-hub\\target\\surefire\\surefirebooter4393690082191226141.jar
I,1,java.io.tmpdir,C:\\Users\\secretuser\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\
I,1,line.separator,\r\n
I,1,java.vm.specification.vendor,Oracle Corporation
I,1,user.variant,
I,1,os.name,Windows 10
I,1,sun.jnu.encoding,Cp1252
I,1,java.library.path,C:\\myPath\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_152\\jre\\bin;C:\\WINDOWS\\Sun\\Java\\bin;C:\\WINDOWS\\system32;C:\\WINDOWS;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SDKs\\Azure\\CLI2\\wbin;C:\\Program Files\\Docker\\Docker\\Resources\\bin;C:\\WINDOWS\\system32;C:\\WINDOWS;C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\Wbem;C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\;C:\\Windows\\CCM;C:\\Program Files\\PuTTY\\;C:\\dev\\bin;C:\\dev\\apache-maven-3.5.0\\bin;C:\\Program Files\\Git\\cmd;C:\\Program Files\\Git\\mingw64\\bin;C:\\Program Files\\Git\\usr\\bin;C:\\myPath\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_152\\bin;C:\\Users\\secretuser\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\WindowsApps;;C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft VS Code\\bin;.
I,1,surefire.test.class.path,C:\\dev\\workspace\\MessageHub.JavaSdk\\lucas-api-hub\\target\\test-classes;C:\\dev\\workspace\\MessageHub.JavaSdk\\lucas-api-hub\\target\\classes;C:\\Users\\secretuser\\.m2\\repository\\com\\fasterxml\\jackson\\core\\jackson-databind\\2.8.4\\jackson-databind-2.8.4.jar;C:\\Users\\secretuser\\.m2\\repository\\com\\fasterxml\\jackson\\core\\jackson-annotations\\2.8.0\\jackson-annotations-2.8.0.jar;C:\\Users\\secretuser\\.m2\\repository\\com\\fasterxml\\jackson\\core\\jackson-core\\2.8.4\\jackson-core-2.8.4.jar;C:\\Users\\secretuser\\.m2\\repository\\com\\google\\inject\\guice\\4.1.0\\guice-4.1.0-no_aop.jar;C:\\Users\\secretuser\\.m2\\repository\\javax\\inject\\javax.inject\\1\\javax.inject-1.jar;C:\\Users\\secretuser\\.m2\\repository\\aopalliance\\aopalliance\\1.0\\aopalliance-1.0.jar;C:\\Users\\secretuser\\.m2\\repository\\com\\google\\guava\\guava\\19.0\\guava-19.0.jar;C:\\Users\\secretuser\\.m2\\repository\\com\\google\\code\\gson\\gson\\2.8.0\\gson-2.8.0.jar;C:\\Users\\secretuser\\.m2\\repository\\com\\google\\oauth-client\\google-oauth-client\\1.22.0\\google-oauth-client-1.22.0.jar;C:\\Users\\secretuser\\.m2\\repository\\com\\google\\http-client\\google-http-client\\1.22.0\\google-http-client-1.22.0.jar;C:\\Users\\secretuser\\.m2\\repository\\com\\google\\code\\findbugs\\jsr305\\1.3.9\\jsr305-1.3.9.jar;C:\\Users\\secretuser\\.m2\\repository\\com\\google\\http-client\\google-http-client-jackson\\1.15.0-rc\\google-http-client-jackson-1.15.0-rc.jar;C:\\Users\\secretuser\\.m2\\repository\\org\\codehaus\\jackson\\jackson-core-asl\\1.9.11\\jackson-core-asl-1.9.11.jar;C:\\Users\\secretuser\\.m2\\repository\\com\\microsoft\\azure\\azure-servicebus\\0.9.7\\azure-servicebus-0.9.7.jar;C:\\Users\\secretuser\\.m2\\repository\\com\\microsoft\\azure\\azure-core\\0.9.7\\azure-core-0.9.7.jar;C:\\Users\\secretuser\\.m2\\repository\\commons-codec\\commons-codec\\1.10\\commons-codec-1.10.jar;C:\\Users\\secretuser\\.m2\\repository\\commons-lang\\commons-lang\\2.6\\commons-lang-2.6.jar;C:\\Users\\secretuser\\.m2\\repository\\org\\apache\\httpcomponents\\httpclient\\4.3.6\\httpclient-4.3.6.jar;C:\\Users\\secretuser\\.m2\\repository\\org\\apache\\httpcomponents\\httpcore\\4.3.3\\httpcore-4.3.3.jar;C:\\Users\\secretuser\\.m2\\repository\\javax\\mail\\mail\\1.4.5\\mail-1.4.5.jar;C:\\Users\\secretuser\\.m2\\repository\\javax\\activation\\activation\\1.1\\activation-1.1.jar;C:\\Users\\secretuser\\.m2\\repository\\com\\sun\\jersey\\jersey-client\\1.19\\jersey-client-1.19.jar;C:\\Users\\secretuser\\.m2\\repository\\com\\sun\\jersey\\jersey-core\\1.19\\jersey-core-1.19.jar;C:\\Users\\secretuser\\.m2\\repository\\javax\\ws\\rs\\jsr311-api\\1.1.1\\jsr311-api-1.1.1.jar;C:\\Users\\secretuser\\.m2\\repository\\com\\sun\\jersey\\jersey-json\\1.19\\jersey-json-1.19.jar;C:\\Users\\secretuser\\.m2\\repository\\org\\codehaus\\jettison\\jettison\\1.1\\jettison-1.1.jar;C:\\Users\\secretuser\\.m2\\repository\\com\\sun\\xml\\bind\\jaxb-impl\\2.2.3-1\\jaxb-impl-2.2.3-1.jar;C:\\Users\\secretuser\\.m2\\repository\\javax\\xml\\bind\\jaxb-api\\2.2.2\\jaxb-api-2.2.2.jar;C:\\Users\\secretuser\\.m2\\repository\\javax\\xml\\stream\\stax-api\\1.0-2\\stax-api-1.0-2.jar;C:\\Users\\secretuser\\.m2\\repository\\org\\codehaus\\jackson\\jackson-mapper-asl\\1.9.2\\jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.2.jar;C:\\Users\\secretuser\\.m2\\repository\\org\\codehaus\\jackson\\jackson-jaxrs\\1.9.2\\jackson-jaxrs-1.9.2.jar;C:\\Users\\secretuser\\.m2\\repository\\org\\codehaus\\jackson\\jackson-xc\\1.9.2\\jackson-xc-1.9.2.jar;C:\\Users\\secretuser\\.m2\\repository\\commons-logging\\commons-logging\\1.1.1\\commons-logging-1.1.1.jar;C:\\Users\\secretuser\\.m2\\repository\\com\\microsoft\\azure\\azure-storage\\4.4.0\\azure-storage-4.4.0.jar;C:\\Users\\secretuser\\.m2\\repository\\org\\slf4j\\slf4j-api\\1.7.12\\slf4j-api-1.7.12.jar;C:\\Users\\secretuser\\.m2\\repository\\org\\apache\\commons\\commons-lang3\\3.4\\commons-lang3-3.4.jar;C:\\Users\\secretuser\\.m2\\repository\\com\\microsoft\\azure\\azure-keyvault-core\\0.8.0\\azure-keyvault-core-0.8.0.jar;C:\\Users\\secretuser\\.m2\\repository\\org\\core4j\\core4j\\0.6\\core4j-0.6.jar;C:\\Users\\secretuser\\.m2\\repository\\org\\bouncycastle\\bcprov-jdk15on\\1.55\\bcprov-jdk15on-1.55.jar;C:\\Users\\secretuser\\.m2\\repository\\org\\apache\\qpid\\qpid-jms-client\\0.11.1\\qpid-jms-client-0.11.1.jar;C:\\Users\\secretuser\\.m2\\repository\\org\\apache\\geronimo\\specs\\geronimo-jms_1.1_spec\\1.1.1\\geronimo-jms_1.1_spec-1.1.1.jar;C:\\Users\\secretuser\\.m2\\repository\\org\\apache\\qpid\\proton-j\\0.14.0\\proton-j-0.14.0.jar;C:\\Users\\secretuser\\.m2\\repository\\io\\netty\\netty-buffer\\4.0.41.Final\\netty-buffer-4.0.41.Final.jar;C:\\Users\\secretuser\\.m2\\repository\\io\\netty\\netty-common\\4.0.41.Final\\netty-common-4.0.41.Final.jar;C:\\Users\\secretuser\\.m2\\repository\\io\\netty\\netty-handler\\4.0.41.Final\\netty-handler-4.0.41.Final.jar;C:\\Users\\secretuser\\.m2\\repository\\io\\netty\\netty-codec\\4.0.41.Final\\netty-codec-4.0.41.Final.jar;C:\\Users\\secretuser\\.m2\\repository\\io\\netty\\netty-transport\\4.0.41.Final\\netty-transport-4.0.41.Final.jar;C:\\Users\\secretuser\\.m2\\repository\\io\\netty\\netty-codec-http\\4.0.41.Final\\netty-codec-http-4.0.41.Final.jar;C:\\Users\\secretuser\\.m2\\repository\\junit\\junit\\4.11\\junit-4.11.jar;C:\\Users\\secretuser\\.m2\\repository\\org\\hamcrest\\hamcrest-core\\1.3\\hamcrest-core-1.3.jar;
I,1,java.specification.name,Java Platform API Specification
I,1,java.class.version,52.0
I,1,sun.management.compiler,HotSpot 64-Bit Tiered Compilers
I,1,os.version,10.0
I,1,user.home,C:\\Users\\secretuser
I,1,user.timezone,
I,1,java.awt.printerjob,sun.awt.windows.WPrinterJob
I,1,java.specification.version,1.8
I,1,file.encoding,Cp1252
I,1,user.name,secretuser
I,1,java.class.path,C:\\dev\\workspace\\MessageHub.JavaSdk\\lucas-api-hub\\target\\test-classes;C:\\dev\\workspace\\MessageHub.JavaSdk\\lucas-api-hub\\target\\classes;C:\\Users\\secretuser\\.m2\\repository\\com\\fasterxml\\jackson\\core\\jackson-databind\\2.8.4\\jackson-databind-2.8.4.jar;C:\\Users\\secretuser\\.m2\\repository\\com\\fasterxml\\jackson\\core\\jackson-annotations\\2.8.0\\jackson-annotations-2.8.0.jar;C:\\Users\\secretuser\\.m2\\repository\\com\\fasterxml\\jackson\\core\\jackson-core\\2.8.4\\jackson-core-2.8.4.jar;C:\\Users\\secretuser\\.m2\\repository\\com\\google\\inject\\guice\\4.1.0\\guice-4.1.0-no_aop.jar;C:\\Users\\secretuser\\.m2\\repository\\javax\\inject\\javax.inject\\1\\javax.inject-1.jar;C:\\Users\\secretuser\\.m2\\repository\\aopalliance\\aopalliance\\1.0\\aopalliance-1.0.jar;C:\\Users\\secretuser\\.m2\\repository\\com\\google\\guava\\guava\\19.0\\guava-19.0.jar;C:\\Users\\secretuser\\.m2\\repository\\com\\google\\code\\gson\\gson\\2.8.0\\gson-2.8.0.jar;C:\\Users\\secretuser\\.m2\\repository\\com\\google\\oauth-client\\google-oauth-client\\1.22.0\\google-oauth-client-1.22.0.jar;C:\\Users\\secretuser\\.m2\\repository\\com\\google\\http-client\\google-http-client\\1.22.0\\google-http-client-1.22.0.jar;C:\\Users\\secretuser\\.m2\\repository\\com\\google\\code\\findbugs\\jsr305\\1.3.9\\jsr305-1.3.9.jar;C:\\Users\\secretuser\\.m2\\repository\\com\\google\\http-client\\google-http-client-jackson\\1.15.0-rc\\google-http-client-jackson-1.15.0-rc.jar;C:\\Users\\secretuser\\.m2\\repository\\org\\codehaus\\jackson\\jackson-core-asl\\1.9.11\\jackson-core-asl-1.9.11.jar;C:\\Users\\secretuser\\.m2\\repository\\com\\microsoft\\azure\\azure-servicebus\\0.9.7\\azure-servicebus-0.9.7.jar;C:\\Users\\secretuser\\.m2\\repository\\com\\microsoft\\azure\\azure-core\\0.9.7\\azure-core-0.9.7.jar;C:\\Users\\secretuser\\.m2\\repository\\commons-codec\\commons-codec\\1.10\\commons-codec-1.10.jar;C:\\Users\\secretuser\\.m2\\repository\\commons-lang\\commons-lang\\2.6\\commons-lang-2.6.jar;C:\\Users\\secretuser\\.m2\\repository\\org\\apache\\httpcomponents\\httpclient\\4.3.6\\httpclient-4.3.6.jar;C:\\Users\\secretuser\\.m2\\repository\\org\\apache\\httpcomponents\\httpcore\\4.3.3\\httpcore-4.3.3.jar;C:\\Users\\secretuser\\.m2\\repository\\javax\\mail\\mail\\1.4.5\\mail-1.4.5.jar;C:\\Users\\secretuser\\.m2\\repository\\javax\\activation\\activation\\1.1\\activation-1.1.jar;C:\\Users\\secretuser\\.m2\\repository\\com\\sun\\jersey\\jersey-client\\1.19\\jersey-client-1.19.jar;C:\\Users\\secretuser\\.m2\\repository\\com\\sun\\jersey\\jersey-core\\1.19\\jersey-core-1.19.jar;C:\\Users\\secretuser\\.m2\\repository\\javax\\ws\\rs\\jsr311-api\\1.1.1\\jsr311-api-1.1.1.jar;C:\\Users\\secretuser\\.m2\\repository\\com\\sun\\jersey\\jersey-json\\1.19\\jersey-json-1.19.jar;C:\\Users\\secretuser\\.m2\\repository\\org\\codehaus\\jettison\\jettison\\1.1\\jettison-1.1.jar;C:\\Users\\secretuser\\.m2\\repository\\com\\sun\\xml\\bind\\jaxb-impl\\2.2.3-1\\jaxb-impl-2.2.3-1.jar;C:\\Users\\secretuser\\.m2\\repository\\javax\\xml\\bind\\jaxb-api\\2.2.2\\jaxb-api-2.2.2.jar;C:\\Users\\secretuser\\.m2\\repository\\javax\\xml\\stream\\stax-api\\1.0-2\\stax-api-1.0-2.jar;C:\\Users\\secretuser\\.m2\\repository\\org\\codehaus\\jackson\\jackson-mapper-asl\\1.9.2\\jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.2.jar;C:\\Users\\secretuser\\.m2\\repository\\org\\codehaus\\jackson\\jackson-jaxrs\\1.9.2\\jackson-jaxrs-1.9.2.jar;C:\\Users\\secretuser\\.m2\\repository\\org\\codehaus\\jackson\\jackson-xc\\1.9.2\\jackson-xc-1.9.2.jar;C:\\Users\\secretuser\\.m2\\repository\\commons-logging\\commons-logging\\1.1.1\\commons-logging-1.1.1.jar;C:\\Users\\secretuser\\.m2\\repository\\com\\microsoft\\azure\\azure-storage\\4.4.0\\azure-storage-4.4.0.jar;C:\\Users\\secretuser\\.m2\\repository\\org\\slf4j\\slf4j-api\\1.7.12\\slf4j-api-1.7.12.jar;C:\\Users\\secretuser\\.m2\\repository\\org\\apache\\commons\\commons-lang3\\3.4\\commons-lang3-3.4.jar;C:\\Users\\secretuser\\.m2\\repository\\com\\microsoft\\azure\\azure-keyvault-core\\0.8.0\\azure-keyvault-core-0.8.0.jar;C:\\Users\\secretuser\\.m2\\repository\\org\\core4j\\core4j\\0.6\\core4j-0.6.jar;C:\\Users\\secretuser\\.m2\\repository\\org\\bouncycastle\\bcprov-jdk15on\\1.55\\bcprov-jdk15on-1.55.jar;C:\\Users\\secretuser\\.m2\\repository\\org\\apache\\qpid\\qpid-jms-client\\0.11.1\\qpid-jms-client-0.11.1.jar;C:\\Users\\secretuser\\.m2\\repository\\org\\apache\\geronimo\\specs\\geronimo-jms_1.1_spec\\1.1.1\\geronimo-jms_1.1_spec-1.1.1.jar;C:\\Users\\secretuser\\.m2\\repository\\org\\apache\\qpid\\proton-j\\0.14.0\\proton-j-0.14.0.jar;C:\\Users\\secretuser\\.m2\\repository\\io\\netty\\netty-buffer\\4.0.41.Final\\netty-buffer-4.0.41.Final.jar;C:\\Users\\secretuser\\.m2\\repository\\io\\netty\\netty-common\\4.0.41.Final\\netty-common-4.0.41.Final.jar;C:\\Users\\secretuser\\.m2\\repository\\io\\netty\\netty-handler\\4.0.41.Final\\netty-handler-4.0.41.Final.jar;C:\\Users\\secretuser\\.m2\\repository\\io\\netty\\netty-codec\\4.0.41.Final\\netty-codec-4.0.41.Final.jar;C:\\Users\\secretuser\\.m2\\repository\\io\\netty\\netty-transport\\4.0.41.Final\\netty-transport-4.0.41.Final.jar;C:\\Users\\secretuser\\.m2\\repository\\io\\netty\\netty-codec-http\\4.0.41.Final\\netty-codec-http-4.0.41.Final.jar;C:\\Users\\secretuser\\.m2\\repository\\junit\\junit\\4.11\\junit-4.11.jar;C:\\Users\\secretuser\\.m2\\repository\\org\\hamcrest\\hamcrest-core\\1.3\\hamcrest-core-1.3.jar;
I,1,java.vm.specification.version,1.8
I,1,sun.arch.data.model,64
I,1,java.home,C:\\myPath\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_152\\jre
I,1,sun.java.command,C:\\dev\\workspace\\MessageHub.JavaSdk\\lucas-api-hub\\target\\surefire\\surefirebooter4393690082191226141.jar C:\\dev\\workspace\\MessageHub.JavaSdk\\lucas-api-hub\\target\\surefire\\surefire2387848635455087535tmp C:\\dev\\workspace\\MessageHub.JavaSdk\\lucas-api-hub\\target\\surefire\\surefire_08471100731569808288tmp
I,1,java.specification.vendor,Oracle Corporation
I,1,user.language,en
I,1,user.language.format,nl
I,1,awt.toolkit,sun.awt.windows.WToolkit
I,1,java.vm.info,mixed mode
I,1,java.version,1.8.0_152
I,1,java.ext.dirs,C:\\myPath\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_152\\jre\\lib\\ext;C:\\WINDOWS\\Sun\\Java\\lib\\ext
I,1,sun.boot.class.path,C:\\myPath\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_152\\jre\\lib\\resources.jar;C:\\myPath\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_152\\jre\\lib\\rt.jar;C:\\myPath\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_152\\jre\\lib\\sunrsasign.jar;C:\\myPath\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_152\\jre\\lib\\jsse.jar;C:\\myPath\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_152\\jre\\lib\\jce.jar;C:\\myPath\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_152\\jre\\lib\\charsets.jar;C:\\myPath\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_152\\jre\\lib\\jfr.jar;C:\\myPath\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_152\\jre\\classes
I,1,sun.stderr.encoding,cp437
I,1,java.vendor,Oracle Corporation
I,1,localRepository,C:\\Users\\secretuser\\.m2\\repository
I,1,file.separator,\\
I,1,java.vendor.url.bug,http:\/\/bugreport.sun.com\/bugreport\/
I,1,sun.cpu.endian,little
I,1,sun.io.unicode.encoding,UnicodeLittle
I,1,sun.stdout.encoding,cp437
I,1,sun.desktop,windows
I,1,sun.cpu.isalist,amd64
1,1,org.apache.maven.surefire.jlucas.JlucasProvider,com.lucas.java.util.TestHashMapExtensions,null,null,null
5,1,com.lucas.java.util.TestHashMapExtensions,testTryGet(com.lucas.java.util.TestHashMapExtensions),null,null,null
6,1,com.lucas.java.util.TestHashMapExtensions,testTryGet(com.lucas.java.util.TestHashMapExtensions),null,null,null
2,1,org.apache.maven.surefire.jlucas.JlucasProvider,com.lucas.java.util.TestHashMapExtensions,null,null,null
1,1,org.apache.maven.surefire.jlucas.JlucasProvider,com.lucas.java.util.TestIterableUtilities,null,null,null
5,1,com.lucas.java.util.TestIterableUtilities,testGetSize(com.lucas.java.util.TestIterableUtilities),null,null,null
6,1,com.lucas.java.util.TestIterableUtilities,testGetSize(com.lucas.java.util.TestIterableUtilities),null,null,null
2,1,org.apache.maven.surefire.jlucas.JlucasProvider,com.lucas.java.util.TestIterableUtilities,null,null,null
1,1,org.apache.maven.surefire.jlucas.JlucasProvider,com.lucas.java.util.TestU4String,null,null,null
5,1,com.lucas.java.util.TestU4String,testIsNullOrEmpty(com.lucas.java.util.TestU4String),null,null,null
6,1,com.lucas.java.util.TestU4String,testIsNullOrEmpty(com.lucas.java.util.TestU4String),null,null,null
5,1,com.lucas.java.util.TestU4String,testIsNullOrWhiteSpace(com.lucas.java.util.TestU4String),null,null,null
6,1,com.lucas.java.util.TestU4String,testIsNullOrWhiteSpace(com.lucas.java.util.TestU4String),null,null,null
2,1,org.apache.maven.surefire.jlucas.JlucasProvider,com.lucas.java.util.TestU4String,null,null,null
1,1,org.apache.maven.surefire.jlucas.JlucasProvider,com.lucas.java.util.TestU4URLDecoder,null,null,null
5,1,com.lucas.java.util.TestU4URLDecoder,testDecode(com.lucas.java.util.TestU4URLDecoder),null,null,null
6,1,com.lucas.java.util.TestU4URLDecoder,testDecode(com.lucas.java.util.TestU4URLDecoder),null,null,null
2,1,org.apache.maven.surefire.jlucas.JlucasProvider,com.lucas.java.util.TestU4URLDecoder,null,null,null
1,1,org.apache.maven.surefire.jlucas.JlucasProvider,com.lucas.java.util.TestU4URLEncoder,null,null,null
5,1,com.lucas.java.util.TestU4URLEncoder,testEncode(com.lucas.java.util.TestU4URLEncoder),null,null,null
6,1,com.lucas.java.util.TestU4URLEncoder,testEncode(com.lucas.java.util.TestU4URLEncoder),null,null,null
2,1,org.apache.maven.surefire.jlucas.JlucasProvider,com.lucas.java.util.TestU4URLEncoder,null,null,null
Z,0,BYE!
```

Is there a known problem with CMD? or am i looking in the wrong direction?

Comment: And when running with <b>maven-surefire-plugin:2.20.1</b>

    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.20.1:test (default-test) on project lucas-api-hub: There are test failures.
    [ERROR]
    [ERROR] Please refer to C:\dev\..\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.
    [ERROR] Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date]-jvmRun[N].dump, [date].dumpstream and [date]-jvmRun[N].dumpstream.
    [ERROR] Error occurred in starting fork, check output in log